# C++/CLI: ProgressBar->Value

Tags: visual-c++, datetime, c++-cli, progress-bar

Does anyone know what's wrong with the code below? The `this->progressBar1->Value` part worked by the `button_click_event` but not in this snippet. I've been messing around with it but to no avail:

```
int Trouble ()
{
int hour = System::DateTime::Now.Hour;
this->progressBar1->Value = hour;
return 0;
}
```

This code snippet is part of a WinForm and it is located in the `#pragma endregion` part of my code (BTW This is Visual C++). As always I will apperciate any help or suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: @Francis: Get into the habit of including the actual error message when asking for help.

Comment: THERE'S NO ERROR!!! That's the freaky part, and the WinForm is not working...

Comment: @Francis: Then you'll need to show more code, especially the function which calls `Trouble`.

Comment: There's no function that calls it; this code is stand-alone.

Comment: So you can remove it from your code, and the program still compiles?

Comment: @Francis: Well that certainly explains why it doesn't "work".  It's not sufficient to write a function, you also have to call it at an appropriate time.

Comment: Drop a Timer on the form.  Set its Enabled property to true and Interval to 1000.  Double-click it, call Trouble() in the Tick event handler.  Look at it for at least an hour.  Contemplate why you are returning 0 in the mean time.

Comment: OK, I'll try that later, Hans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you've made this a free function rather than a member function of your class. Place this definition inside your class' definition (probably under the `private:` access modifier) and you'll get the behavior you expect. Also, do some reading on "scope", as it's a very fundamental concept and not understanding it is why you're having this problem.

Comment: Hm... got any other suggestions? The code's not working wherever I put it.

Comment: @Francis : Yes -- post the entire code file to pastebin/ideone/codepad and give us the link. This way we can examine the definition in its surrounding context to identify the problem.

Comment: @Francis : Thank you. Now, what specific line of code in that file is giving you problems, and what are the details of those problems (i.e., are they compiler errors? Unexpected runtime behavior?)?

Comment: There are no errors, that's the freaky part! It's just the function, appropriately named `Trouble`, that is not working the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: @Francis : Define "*not working the way it's supposed to be*". How can anyone diagnose this without knowing both 1) what you expect and 2) what is actually happening? Also, there is no function named `Trouble` in the code in that link.

Comment: OK, Idjarn stated that I have to call the function. I'll see if it works.

Comment: Hmm... not working. Any other suggestions, please? I will appreciate any comments, answers, or suggestions. :)

Comment: @Francis : _What's_ not working, and what does "not working" mean? These questions have both been asked before.

Comment: The progressbar is not moving to the set value, it just stays at zero. However, the button I placed on the WinForm, when clicked, will do the `this->progressbar1->value = 5;` and that make it move! I don't understand why my code snippet doesn't make the progressbar move to the set value.

Comment: @Francis : Where are you calling the function? You've not posted any code that does anything other than define it...

Comment: Yeh, I think that's it. I've just moved the function, and now it's working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this exchange of comments may qualify as an answer:

> @Francis: Then you'll need to show more code, especially the function which calls `Trouble`. – Ben Voigt
>
> There's no function that calls it; this code is stand-alone. – Francis Lau
>
> So you can remove it from your code, and the program still compiles? – Ben Voigt
>
> You may say that. – Francis Lau

That certainly explains why it doesn't "work". It's not sufficient to write a function, you also have to call it at an appropriate time.